# RuntimeError: expected type torch.cuda.FloatTensor but got torch.FloatTensor

Tags: pytorch

I keep getting the error message below. I cannot seem to pinpoint to the tensor mentioned. Below you'll find the trainer.py and main.py modules. The model I am developing is GAN on CelebA dataset. I am running the code on a remote server so have spent a handful amount of time debugging my model.

This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "main.py", line 47, in main
    trainer.train(train_loader)
  File "/home/path/trainer.py", line 45, in train
    d_loss_cls = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_cls, label_org, size_average=False) / out_cls.size(0)
  File "/home/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2077, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
    return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)
RuntimeError: expected type torch.cuda.FloatTensor but got torch.FloatTensor
```

trainer.py

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from model import Discriminator, Generator
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

class Trainer():
    def __init__(self, opt):
        # Generator
        self.G = Generator(64, 5, 6)
        # Discriminator
        self.D = Discriminator(128, 64, 5, 6)
        # Generator optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.G.parameters(), opt.lr)
        self.d_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.D.parameters(), opt.lr)
        self.opt = opt
        if self.opt.cuda:
            self.G = self.G.cuda()
            self.D = self.D.cuda()

    def train(self, data_loader):
        """Function to train the model
        """
        print('Training model')
        writer_d = SummaryWriter('runs/disc') # discriminator writer
        writer_g = SummaryWriter('runs/gen') # generator writer
        print('Start training...')
        for epoch in tqdm(range(self.opt.epochs)):
            for x_real, label_org in tqdm(data_loader):
                pass
                # Generate target domain labels randomly.
                rand_idx = torch.randperm(label_org.size(0))
                label_trg = label_org[rand_idx]
                c_org = label_org.clone()
                c_trg = label_org.clone()
                if self.opt.cuda:
                    x_real = x_real.cuda()           # Input images
                    c_org = c_org.cuda()             # Original domain labels
                    c_trg = c_trg.cuda()             # Target domain labels
                    label_org = label_org.cuda()     # Labels for computing classification loss
                    label_trg = label_trg.cuda()     # Labels for computing classification loss

                out_src, out_cls = self.D(x_real)
                d_loss_real = - torch.mean(out_src)
                d_loss_cls = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_cls, label_org, size_average=False) / out_cls.size(0)

                # Compute loss with fake images
                x_fake = self.G(x_real, c_trg)
                out_src, out_cls = self.D(x_fake.detach())
                d_loss_fake = torch.mean(out_src)

                # Compute loss for gradient penalty
                alpha = torch.rand(x_real.size(0), 1, 1, 1).cuda()
                x_hat = (alpha * x_real.data + (1 - alpha) * x_fake.data).requires_grad_(True)
                out_src, _ = self.D(x_hat)

                # Backward and optimize
                d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake + d_loss_cls
                self.g_optimizer.zero_grad()
                self.d_optimizer.zero_grad()
                d_loss.backward()
                self.d_optimizer.step()

                if (i + 1) % 2 == 0:
                    # Original-to-target domain
                    x_fake = self.G(x_real, c_trg)
                    out_src, out_cls = self.D(x_fake)
                    g_loss_fake = - torch.mean(out_src)
                    g_loss_cls = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_cls, label_trg, size_average=False) / out_cls.size(0)

                    # Target-to-original domain
                    x_reconst = self.G(x_fake, c_org)
                    g_loss_rec = torch.mean(torch.abs(x_real - x_reconst))

                    # Backward and optimize
                    g_loss = g_loss_fake + g_loss_rec
                    self.g_optimizer.zero_grad()
                    self.d_optimizer.zero_grad() 
                    g_loss.backward()
                    self.g_optimizer.step()

                # write loss to tensorboard
                writer_d.add_scalar('data/loss', d_loss, epoch)
                writer_d.add_scalar('data/loss', g_loss, epoch)
            print('Finished Training')


    def test(self, data_loader):
        with torch.no_grad():
            for i, (x_real, c_org) in enumerate(data_loader):

                # Prepare input images and target domain labels.
                if self.opt.cuda:
                    x_real = x_real.cuda()

                # Translate images.
                x_fake_list = [x_real]
                for c_trg in c_trg_list:
                    x_fake_list.append(self.G(x_real, c_trg))
```

main.py

```py
import argparse
import random
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from preprocess import pre_process
from celeb_dataset import CelebDataset
from trainer import Trainer


# Setting up the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--workers', type=int, help='number of data loading workers', default=4)
parser.add_argument('--batchSize', type=int, default=8, help='input batch size')
parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=20, help='number of epochs to train')
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.0002, help='learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--cuda', action='store_true', help='enables cuda')
parser.add_argument('--manualSeed', type=int, help='manual seed')
parser.add_argument('--dataset_path', type=str, default='./data/celeba', help='dataset path')

opt = parser.parse_args()
print(opt)

if opt.manualSeed is None:
    opt.manualSeed = random.randint(1, 10000)
print("Random Seed: ", opt.manualSeed)


def main(opt):
    # Setup  the parameters for the training/testing
    params = {
        'batch_size': opt.batchSize,
        'shuffle': True,
        'num_workers': opt.workers
    }

    # preprocess and setup dataset and datalader
    processed_data = pre_process(opt.dataset_path)
    train_dataset = CelebDataset(processed_data[:-2000])
    test_dataset = CelebDataset(processed_data[2000:])
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, **params)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, **params)

    trainer = Trainer(opt)
    trainer.train(train_loader)
    trainer.test(test_loader)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(opt)
```

Comment: probably you forgot to convert your input tensors `.to('cuda')` before passing them to your trainer.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because one of `out_cls, label_org` is not on the GPU.

Where does your code enact the `parser.add_argument('--cuda', action='store_true', help='enables cuda')` option?

Perhaps something like:

```
trainer = Trainer(opt)
if opt.cuda:
    trainer = trainer.cuda()
```

Comment: I have updated main.py (fifth to last line) to include cuda but same issue persists. I have just uploaded all the code files related to my GAN.

Comment: Can you print both `out_cls.device` and `label_org.device` before the line where it breaks, and then see which one is not on the GPU?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The CLS device was indeed on CPU. I have now run across other errors that I will attempt to troubleshoot. Thank you!